# Comparing Textbox value to cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I programmed a communication tool for the production floor. This tool will register what they have done, who has done it and on what time.

The following should check whether the textbox value equals the value in the worksheet **or** if the textbox **(textbox is TextTools1)** is empty. If this is true, then nothing should happen and the thus the value of the textbox is gonna stay the same. 
If the textbox is not empty or is not equal to what has been previously saved in the worksheet (thus the value has changed), then it should be registered which operator has done it and what date and what time.

It works when the textbox is empty, but when the value of the textbox has stayed the same (thus TextTools.value=ActiveCell.Offset(0,23).value **(Correct)**) it still adds the operators name, date and time.

Something is going wrong when trying to compare the textbox value and the cell value, but cant put my finger on it.

```
    Sheets("Checklist & overdracht").Visible = True
Sheets("Checklist & overdracht").Select
If TextTools1.Value = Range("AZ1").Value Or TextTools1.Value = Empty Then
    Sheets("Checklist & overdracht").Select
    rowloc1.Value = ActiveCell.Row
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 23).Value = TextTools1.Value
Else
    Sheets("Checklist & overdracht").Select
    rowloc1.Value = ActiveCell.Row
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 23).Value = TextTools1.Value & " " & "(" & cboOperator.Value & " " & Format(DateValue(CStr(Now)), "short date") & " " & Format(TimeValue(CStr(Now)), "hh:mm") & ")"
End If
```

Edit; changed it to the code above. I tested this in another userform (and used f8) and it works brilliantly, but when I put in the userform that will actually run this code, than it doesnt have the same result...

Edit2; So apparently something goes wrong with `Range(AZ1).Value` reference. Because when I enter a random value instead of the range and then run the code, it does work. Is there a different way of referencing?

Comment: Is this textbox on a userform? or is it an activeX control on the worksheet?

Comment: Also, I think if you stepped through the code (using f8) you could easily figure out what the compiler sees the values of these controls and it should help illustrate what the issue is.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I had to figure out how to walk through the code, because there was a lot of other code before this line that caused some difficulties.
I made a seperate userform for this specific line.

First of all; the textbox is in an userform.

Second; The compiler says for `ActiveCell.Offset(0,23).Value` it is empty while there is text in this cell. Not sure why it does this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok based on your comments

Stop using active cell when code from a user form is communicating to the compiler what sheet is what. You need to fully qualify what sheet you are using. Im not entirely sure where in the code the active sheet is being set but I am fairly certain the answer is never. Another reason selecting and referencing .ActiveWhatever is bad is a cardinal sin of vba is interacting with the actual application object instead of doing everything in memory. It bogs everything done and performance suffers considerably. When you start writing pretty dense stuff then you will inevitably suffer from issues where the compiler gets confused as to what thing it should be looking at and you'll have a grand ol' time of troubleshooting that nonsense.

Also, it might be a good idea to check for more than just "=Empty". What if there is a null or empty string? I tend to check for:

```
 .value = "" OR ISNULL(.Value)=True OR .Value = vbNullstring
```

this isnt real feedback though - tons of people have different ways of doing the same thing.

Try:

```
 Thisworkbook.Sheets("YOURSHEETNAME").Range("YOURRANGE").Offset(0,23).Value = Someothervalue.
```

Let me know if youre still facing issues.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I still cannot get it to work. Referencing with `ThisWorkbook...` doesn't work. When I test the piece of code in a separate userform it still works. When the values are the same or the cell is empty it jumps to the first clause and ELSE it jumps to the second. But when I implement this in my actual userform it doesnt work.

Comment: Where is your code being placed? Worksheet? Module? Behind userform?